# OpenPyXL - Header/Footer - Can't write header to sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a header to a spreadsheet I've created for work. I have followed the openpyxl docs as precisely as I can. However, it still won't give me a header. Here is a simple example (almost exactly as the docs) that will not work for me:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.oddHeader.text = "fffffffffffffffffff"
ws.oddHeader.size = 14
ws.oddHeader.font = "Tahoma,Bold"
ws.oddHeader.color = "CC3366"
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'hello'
wb.save('C:/Users/ffffffff/Desktop/test.xlsx')
```

Docs: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/print_settings.html

Comment: Why won't it work? Can you include the error message?

Comment: It's virtually impossible for us to assist without knowing exactly what the problem is (are you getting an error message?  What is it actually doing vs. what you expected? etc)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to writing questions. It simply will not write a header with the text 'fffffffffff'. There is no error.

Comment: Could be a bug. Don't use this stuff myself and it was completely rewritten in 2.4

Comment: @CharlieClark You mean you don't use header/footers? Would you mind helping me file a bug report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've looked at this in more detail and the problem is in the openpyxl documentation. Headers and footers have three areas: left, centre/center and right and at least one of these must be used.

Your code only needs to be changed slightly to work:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.oddHeader.center.text = "fffffffffffffffffff"
ws.oddHeader.center.size = 14
ws.oddHeader.center.font = "Tahoma,Bold"
ws.oddHeader.center.color = "CC3366"
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'hello'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```